# How to reset asp.net session with ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session

I am trying to reset an asp.net session with ajax, but it's not working. What do I need to do to trigger a reset on the session time or IIS worker process

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool KeepAlive()
{
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not totally sure, but I think the session timer will be triggered if you use the WebMethod attribute like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static bool KeepAlive()
{
    return true;
}
```

I would try it out myself, but I'm using my mac atm... :P

Comment: No session object can be accessed if EnableSession=True isn't specified. So I'm guessing you're right too.

Comment: I set my IIS worker process to one minute and ajaxed pinged it every 15 seconds and this seemed to reset the session. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If EnableSession is true, then any request will reset the session to start at the beginning. However the IIS worker process is controlled by the Application Pool settings and cannot be controlled by an external request of some sort.